# How to include Debian repository from different architecture

Tags: debian, apt, aptitude

I am running AMD64 Debian. I need to install software from external vendor which supports i386 architecture only.

While I can add their repository to sources.list, those i386 packages do not appear in package list and thus aptitude does not resolve dependencies.

Is there a way how to force i386 packages to appear in the list on AMD64 system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you could get the packages to install, it is likely that they won't work right.

What you may have to do is build a x86 chroot, and then run the application in the chroot.  Here is [an article](http://alioth.debian.org/docman/view.php/30192/21/debian-amd64-howto.html#id292205) that describes doing this, though you probably should use stable release and not sid, like the article suggests.

Also see:

- http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/356
- http://wiki.debian.org/DebianAMD64Faq

Answer (score 1):

This is the defining use case for [Debian multiarch](http://wiki.debian.org/multiarch). Unfortunately squeeze isnt there yet, but [the future](https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/packageselection-foundations-n-multiarch-support) looks bright.